# How to get multiple users timeline efficiently using twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I want to get time line data for 2 users. Currently I am calling `getUserTimeline("username",paging)` method for both the users and combining the data. Is there any optimal way of doing it, for example, using one twitter api call or is this the only way it can be done? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Twitter APIs does not allow to query for multiple users' timelines.

I guess you already did it, but you should double check that I am not wrong by looking at the official [Twitter APIs documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).

Comment: yeah i checked there api documentation didnt find anything for multiple user time line....thanks.